# Excel: Get values in non-adjacent cells based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet sort of like this:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how to get the totals in cells B1 through B4.

I tried INDEX-MATCH, where I tried to match the words in A1:A4 with the words in row 7, get the numbers relative to them, and then sum them, but it was a lot of Google searching and stabbing in the dark -- every attempt returned an error.

I also tried to INDEX-MATCH the words in A1:A4 with row 7, and then nest a VLOOKUP in there where it'd get the number relative to "visits:" but that didn't work at all either.

Is INDEX-MATCH even the correct function? Any help would be much appreciated, I'm not even sure what to Google anymore.

**EDIT:** I need to use a search function of some kind, like the INDEX-MATCH method, rather that static formulas because the sheet will change periodically and I don't want to have to update the formula every time I add an animal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data table is unusual in structure.
However, if you are gong to keep a fixed rule such that the number of visits is always offset 2 rows and 1 column from the animal type(and that itself is always in row 7), you could do:

In B1:

`=SUM(IF($A$7:$AAA$7=$A1, $B$9:$AAB$9, 0))`

Confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter, and then copy down..

Comment: This worked! Thanks! Wow, that's way simpler than what I was trying.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

DOes this work?

```
=SUM(IF($B$7=A1,$C$9,0),IF($D$7=A1,$E$9,0),IF($F$7=A1,$G$9,0),IF($H$7=A1,$I$9,0))
```

Comment: It could be a potential workaround for now, but I have about 30 animal blocks and I'm adding and subtracting them all the time, so I would have to edit the formula every time I change the sheet. I'm looking for a way to search the entire sheet (or at least all of row 7), find all the dogs, and add together the associated visits (etc. for each animal).

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit the question since I didn't make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sureto have fully grasped your challenge. Yet it seems the following solution would work:
Add the following formula in each box where the number of visits is added as

```
=+SUMIF($A$1:$A$end;animal;$B$1:$B$end)
```

Where end is a number of the last cell in the first and second columns data contain the data.
And animal is the cell that contains the name of the animal.

Therefore in your simple example, the formulas on cells `C9;E9;G9` and `I9` would be respectively:

```
=+SUMIF($A$1:$A$4;B7;$B$1:$B$4) ; =+SUMIF($A$1:$A$4;D7;$B$1:$B$4); =+SUMIF($A$1:$A$4;F7;$B$1:$B$4) and =+SUMIF($A$1:$A$4;H7;$B$1:$B$4).
```